# Recoverable vs Non recoverable schedule

Tags: database, transactions, schedule, serializable

Consider Schedule 1 as

```
    T1                      T2
    R(A)
    A=A-50
    W(A)
                            R(A)
                            A=A+20
                            W(A)
                            Commit
```

```
   R(B)
   //Failure happens here 
   //and T1 Rollbacks
   B=B+50
   Commit
```

Consider Schedule 2 as

```
    T1                      T2
    R(A)
    A=A-50
    W(A)
                            R(A)
                            A=A+20
                            W(A)
```

```
   R(B)
   //Failure happens here 
   //and T1 Rollbacks
   B=B+50
   Commit

                        Commit
```

If the initial value of A=100 then in both the cases value of A will be 100 at the end so how 1st schedule is non recoverable and 2nd one is recoverable?

Also in 1st schedule, the transaction T1 rolls back the value of A after the transaction T2 has committed it. So will the committed value of A also rollback to 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Also in 1st schedule, the transaction T1 rolls back the value of A after the transaction T2 has committed it. So will the committed value of A also rollback to 100?**

*Yes it will rollback to its initial value*

**A recoverable schedule is
one where, for each pair of transactions Ti and Tj such that Tj reads a data item previously
written by Ti, the commit operation of Ti appears before the commit operation
of Tj .**

*** Recoverable schedule = Rollbacking of uncommited transaction *** and

*** Non-recoverable schedule = Rollbacking of commited transaction ***

Comment: According to me, for the first schedule to be non recoverable,we should not be able to get the original value of A (i.e 100) back as T2 commits the value of A when A=70, but you are saying it will roll back to 100.                                     I am confused :(

Comment: @Xylene23 when transaction T1 commits means it writes the value of A and B to the Hard Disk but according to your condition it fails before it commit so the original value is still same as the previous one . How ever in T2 it gets commited but Atomicity is not there which is important part of any Transaction ,So it is not yet commited to in hard disk because it reads dirty value of A. Hope it helps